# Development for different mobile platforms on Mac

Tags: macos, mobile, mobile-phones

I'm developing for iPhone mainly but wonder for what other mobile platform I can develop on my Mac? Info about any mobile platforms (Symbian, Maemo, Win-mobile, Android, Bada etc) is appreciated.

Comment: Please do a service to the community and do not develop for vendor-specific platforms. Let there be one (or more) open platforms.

Comment: Install a virtualization environment (VirtualBox, VMWare, Parallels) and you need not worry about what platform you are using to develop.  I create virtual machines for pretty much every development project just because it keeps each environment isolated and clean.  I don't have to fret too much about being experimental about what I install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Android, of course. Only need to install Eclipse with Android SDK.
For Symbian, from what I have heard as well.

With Windows Mobile could be more complicated. Usually you need Visual Studio with Compact Framework, which as you can guess are only available for Windows.